# Can a camera be a texture?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

i want to make a game using html / javascript with Three.js.
I added moving the road and made the functionality that moves the camera like you were moving the car using arrow keys.

Now i need the camera to have a texture of a car so we would actually move the car.
I already searched the internet and didnt find any helpfull idea.
There's a code:

```
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
    renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    renderer.setClearColor(0xDDDDDD, 1);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, WIDTH/HEIGHT, 0.1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 50; 
    scene.add(camera);

////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////
var Texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( "images/road1.jpg" ); 
Texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
Texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
Texture.repeat.set( 1, 5 );

var Material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: Texture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
var Geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 50, 1, 1);
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(Geometry, Material); 
plane.rotation.set(90, 0, 0);
plane.material.map.offset.y = 1.5;
scene.add(plane);




    function render() {
requestAnimationFrame(render);

if(up==true)
    {
        speed+=0.0004;
        if(speed>max)
            {
                speed=max;
            }
        console.log("speed"+speed );
    }

if(down==true)
    {
        speed-=0.0001;
        if(speed<0.001)
            {
                speed=0;
            }
    }

if(left==true)
    {

                camera.position.x-=0.05;
                console.log("camera left" +camera.position.x  );  

    }

if(right==true)
    {
        camera.position.x+=0.05;
        console.log("camera right" +camera.position.x  );
    }
if(up==false)
    {
        if(speed>0)
            {
                speed-=0.0003;
            }
    }

        plane.material.map.offset.y -=speed;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    render();
```

I deleted much of the code so you could see what im doing and what help i need.
Between ///// is a code for camera. I need this camera to have a texture :)

Comment: Did you try to find obj file for car? you need to load obj file using OBJLoader2 and  add the object and move camera and car object together

Comment: I have a car image in my folder that's all. I was given 60% of the code and i have to add graphics + movement. I'm not good at javascript.

Answer (score 2):

No, camera cannot have/be a texture, but you need to add car object and put camera inside of the car or on top of the car. I found few examples will help your work done:

https://github.com/JunyiYang0925/Car_game_threejs

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_cars.html

https://github.com/Caesor/racing-game

http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2012/05/21/sport-car-in-webgl/

Comment: Hmm :( Our profesor told us to first make the camera movement and gave us grade's for that. I'll have to ask him how this should work then...

Comment: "make the camera movement" doesn't mean "give the camera a visible texture."

Comment: then you don't even need to add car. just imagine your are a car and camera is your eyes. while you are moving, no need to see yourself

Comment: maybe that's what he wanted :D I'll see ;P 
But anyway thanks for the help. Now i know that camera can't have a texture :D

Comment: you are welcome, I think this answer can satisfy your question. add new question if your professor will ask something else